# How to dynamically add a vector in another vector

Tags: r

**So, what am I trying to do?**

I want to iterate an expression *n* times and add it to a vector *x*, then I want to change a parameter (*r*) and iterate again then add those elements to the same vector, without losing the information about the previous iteration.

**What I have tried?**

```
while(rmin<=rmax){
  while(cont!=n){
    y=rmin*x*(1-x)
    x=y
    vec[cont]<-x
    cont=cont+1
 }
for (i in n:length(vec)){
     plotvec[i] <- vec[i]
 }
 cont=0
 rmin=rmin+rstep
}
```

So, as I don't know how to just keep adding numbers to the vector *vec*, I create another vector called *plotvec* that after the code leaves the second *while* it should receive all values of *vec*.

**What I want to know**
How to make it work, because it is not. Also how to make it more clear and elegant. As I am a coding beginner I would ask, if possible, to not use very fancy solutions.

**What results do I expect**
Using those parameters and conditions:

```
rmin<-2.4
rmax<-4.0
rstep<-0.01
n<-1000
x<-0.2
y<-0
i<-0
cont<-0
vec<-numeric()
plotvec<-numeric()
```

To get a vector with all the data I need to plot a **bifucartion diagram**. My objetice is to plot the *plotvec* against the interval between rmin and rmax.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have `v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `v2 <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)` you can combine them with `c(v1, v2)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include sample data so that we can run your code and show expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem (I was overthinking about something that was simpler) but now I have a new problem.

Firstly, the solution I came up (maybe someone in the future might found it useful, idk)

```
  while(rmin<=4){
   while(cont!=n){
    y=rmin*x*(1-x)
    x=y
    vec<-c(vec,x)
    cont=cont+1
   }
   rmin=rmin+rstep
   cont=0
  }
```

And the result I got was that: [bifucation diagram result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6PhX.png)

however I would like to have, in the X axis, a sequence ranging from 2.4 to 4. So I created a sequence like this:

```
xlabel <- seq(from=2.4, to=4, by=0.01)
```

But the result I got when I plot it was not what I was expecting

```
plot(cbind(xlabel,vec),xlab="R", ylab="X")
```

[Unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSqb6.png)